# What is effecting my Android's sound?

Tags: audio, volume, motorola-moto-g5

Recently, while listening to music and YouTube the volume level fluctuates.

It goes from...

what I set it to - to 70% lower volume - to back to what I set it to - to 70% lower, on and on and on.

Headphones and Bluetooth both experience the same volume level up/down effect.

I booted in Safe Mode.  I deleted the last recently added apps I installed over the past 6 months. I have no tasker type apps installed.  I use the phone for calls, web and YouTube.

Nothing has fixed this.

The only thing I can think of is the last update I said "OK" too.

What else can I try?

```
Moto G5 Plus
Android Version/7.0
Android security patch level/1 June 2018
Kernel/3.18.31-perf-gf055b2e-00107-gdc6d2c1
```

Comment: I should add that this phone is a year old and has never had this problem before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. From what I understood, sometimes the sound goes up in volume then when you change it it starts a loop, right? When did the issue start? What happened before the issue arose? Have you tried resetting app preferences: Setting > Apps > three dots > Reset apps? Please observe the device for 24 hours and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Not quite.  Here is my new normal:  I go to YouTube to watch a video.  I set the volume level for my headphones (or Bluetooth).  In a few seconds the volume suddenly (without me doing anything) drops to almost barely perceivable.  In another 30-40 seconds the volume level will jump right back to where I set it.  This repeats indefinably.